# formArrayName inside formGroupName angular

Tags: ionic3, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am creating nested form array that structured like this

[image]

I build my formBuilder like this:

```
  initFormGeneral() {
    return this.generalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      accompanyingSheet: [this.data ? this.data.accompanyingSheet : ''],
      airCirculation: [this.data ? this.data.airCirculation : ''],
      airRenewalRate: [this.data ? this.data.airRenewalRate : ''],
      area: this.buildArea(this.data ? this.data.area : []),
    });
  }

    buildArea(data) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [data ? data.id : ''],
      localActivity: [data ? data.localActivity : ''],
      usualUse: [data ? data.usualUse : ''],
      mpcas:
        [
          this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              id: [''],
              name: [''],
            })
          ]),
        ]
    });
  }
```

So I have a formArrayName inside formGroupName because 'area' is an object and mpcas is array of objects.

Then, I write my html:

```
 <div formGroupName="area">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-label>
                         Local Activity
                      </ion-label>
                      <ion-select formControlName="localActivity">
                        <ion-option *ngFor="let type of localActivityList; let i = index" value="{{type.name}}">{{type.name}}
                        </ion-option>
                      </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>

                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col>
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-label>
                       Usual Use
                      </ion-label>
                      <ion-select formControlName="usualUse">
                        <ion-option *ngFor="let type of usualUseList; let i = index" value="{{type.name}}">{{type.name}}
                        </ion-option>
                      </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>

                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                 <ion-row> 
                  <div formArrayName="mpcas">
                    <div *ngFor="let mpca of area.controls.mpcas.controls; let i=index">
                      <div  [formGroupName]="i">
                        <ion-col>
                          <ion-item>
                            <ion-label>
                             MPCAS
                            </ion-label>
                            <ion-select formControlName="name">
                              <ion-option *ngFor="let type of mpcasList;" value="{{type.name}}">{{type.name}}
                              </ion-option>
                            </ion-select>
                          </ion-item>
                        </ion-col>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ion-row>
             </div>
```

But I `Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined` as an error.
I tried to get the controls from mpcas on console:

```
console.log(this.generalForm.get('area').get('mpcas'));
```

And there is no controls. How is that possible ?

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: area: this.buildArea(this.data.area); here you did mistake